# correct method for an id within a class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a navigation system. CSS based. On a few of the li items I need to be able to customize the way it looks (background colour, font colour etc).

At the moment the top level menu is here: http://www.gardensandhomesdirect.co.uk/menutest

SALE, the bottom menu, is one I am trying to set as having a red background and have tried doing it this way:

```
.side_nav .li-sale { background-color:#900 !important; color:#FFF !important; }
```

However it is getting overuled.

What is the best way to set this up? So I can have custom li classes used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your red background color is for LI which is under green A, so you cannot see that LI.

Just try setting style for child A element:

```
.side_nav ul li.li-sale a { 
    background-color:#900;
    color:#FFF; 
}
```

Comment: thats perfect thank you! I understand now, I hadnt got my 'depths' right for each li and ul etc :)

Answer (score 0):

If you `li`'s are something like this:
`<li class="side_nav" id="li-scale">`

you can call this one in your css with:
`.side_nav #li-scale`

So basically, in your css, you call classes with a `.` and you call id's with a `#`